# Find the average colour on screen in SDL

Tags: c++, sdl-2

in SDL we're trying to find the average colour of the screen. To do so we're reading all the pixel colour values and putting them into an array (Performance is not of concern), for some reason however, GetPixel always returns a colour (0,0,0,0). Ive already established that the  RenderReadPixels works correctly since saving a screenshot works just fine.

```cpp
const Uint32 format = SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888;
SDL_Surface* surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceWithFormat(0, width, height, 32, format); 
SDL_RenderReadPixels(renderer, NULL, format, surface->pixels, surface->pitch);

float* coverage = new float[width*height]; // * allocates memory
coverage[0] = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
{       
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
    {          
        SDL_Color col;
        col = GetPixel(surface, i, j);
        coverage[i * height + j] = (1/3)(col.r + col.b + col.g); //Return coverage value at i, j
        std::cout << coverage[i * height + j];  //Always returns 0
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

SDL_Color GetPixel(SDL_Surface* srf, int x, int y)
{
    SDL_Color color;

    SDL_GetRGBA(get_pixel32(srf, x, y), srf->format, &color.r, &color.g, &color.b, &color.a);

    return color;
}
Uint32 get_pixel32(SDL_Surface* surface, int x, int y)
{
    //Convert the pixels to 32 bit
    Uint32* pixels = (Uint32*)surface->pixels;

    //Get the requested pixel
    return pixels[(y * surface->w) + x];
}
```

Comment: `1/3` is 0 in an `int` context.

Answer (score 0):

`1/3` is always 0 because of the way number promotion works in C++.

Best be explicit about what you want:

```
coverage[i * height + j] = float(col.r + col.b + col.g) / 3.0;
```

Comment: This performs a `double` division, which is probably unintended.

Comment: Can you explain? I'm only seeing single-precision instructions if I enter `float f(int x) {
    return float(x) / 3.0;
}` in godbolt

Comment: Interesting. GCC indeed outputs a float division. Clang does a double division by default, and float with optimizations. MSVC always seems to do a double division. In any case, `decltype` of that expression is double, a true float division would be `/ 3.0f`.